# How to access initializers constants from cucumber scenarios?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I have got a cucumber feature and when running it, I get the following error message:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::CONFIG (NameError)
./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:25:in `xxx'
```

That CONFIG constant is a hash defined in *config/initializers/config.rb*. It is defined correctly when using the application in development/production mode but apparently it's not when called from a cucumber context.

I tried to add an initializer file in features/support with the following code:

```
Dir[Rails.root + "config/initializers/*.rb"].each do |file|
    require file
end
```

But it doesn't change anything.

What do you think about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Cucumber don't load your environment within your steps.
What if you require your config files directly in features/steps?